# How to solve jsx precompile and React dev-tool in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, reactjs

I try to learn how to write react.
But when I write first component with chrome, Chrome's developer tool show the message

`Download the React DevTools for a better development experience`

I have already installed the React DevTools from Chrome's app store.
My code is work, I just want to know how to solve these message.
Is my chrome setting wrong?

Please someone help me fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning for "Download the React DevTools for a better development experience" should be fixed [in React 0.12.0 and above when using the latest React DevTools extension](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/953#issuecomment-59292722). If you're using a version of React earlier than 0.12, or you have an old version of the extension, the message will continue to pop up.

The warning about using the in-browser JSX transformation is just that—it's telling you that you're converting your JSX syntax into JS function calls in the browser, which is slower and requires the relatively large JSX transformer. If you follow the link in the warning, you'll be [taken to a page that explains further](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#jsx):

> **Note:**
>
> The in-browser JSX transformer is fairly large and results in extraneous computation client-side that can be avoided. Do not use it in production — see the next section.
>
> **Productionizing: Precompiled JSX**
>
> If you have npm, you can simply run `npm install -g react-tools` to install our command-line jsx tool. This tool will translate files that use JSX syntax to plain JavaScript files that can run directly in the browser. It will also watch directories for you and automatically transform files when they are changed; for example: `jsx --watch src/ build/`.
>
> By default JSX files with a `.js` extension are transformed. Use `jsx --extension jsx src/ build/` to transform files with a `.jsx` extension.
>
> Run `jsx --help` for more information on how to use this tool.

Comment: I use React 0.13.3 and it still show up React DevTool